# How to add a conditional statement to a directive based on presence of an attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I tried and what I'm trying to make:

**HTML:**

```
<update-field name="test" cap></update-field>
```

**JS:**

```
 scope: {
      name: "@",
      cap: "@"
 },
 controller: function() {
        },
 link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
   scope.submit = function($event, object) {
      query.first({
          success: function(object) {
        if (scope.cap) {
           // do stuff
```

But `scope.cap` doesn't return `true` if I include `cap` in the HTML (which is what I'm trying to accomplish). What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link function already has `attr` parameter.This `attr` to contains all the attributes added to the element.

So, inside link function, you can check

```
if (attr.cap != null) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a property is within an object using the `in` keyword. `attr` should have a property `cap` if you add the attribute `cap`, and if not, then the property will not be present.

```
'cap' in attr // <--- true or false
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in